# wsl2 and win11: can't move GUI application

Tags: terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running GUI applications from wsl2 (Ubuntu 20.04) on Win 11. To make things work, I do a export DISPLAY=:0 in .bashrc, and I run Xserver with "Disable access control" enabled.

Applications start properly, however, I can't move the windows. It's nasty, since the mouse cursor for some applications are off.
Things are not working anymore after updating to Win11.

Any clues?

Comment: that seems to be 100% a problem of the windows-native X server side of things; don't really know how our Unix/Linux experience will help you there.

Comment: I observe same behavior with WSL2
I use Eclipse on Ubuntu in WSL
sometimes running eclipse simply disappears.
When I try to start it once again, the first instance pops up, together with second one. First instance is already inaccessible. Looks like it is not receiving inputs either from mouse nor keyboard.
Only wsl --shutdown helps


WSL version: 2.0.9.0
Kernel version: 5.15.133.1-1
WSLg version: 1.0.59
MSRDC version: 1.2.4677
Direct3D version: 1.611.1-81528511
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.19045.3570